# How to calculate the probability of many events in series?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to determine the correct method to calculate the probabilities of this problem:

Assume a piece of dust is travelling through a tube made up of 5 sections. If the particle touches a wall, it will stick and not travel further. I want to determine the probability that the particle will pass through all sections of the tube without getting stuck.

Assume I have already obtained the probabilities of the particle getting stuck in each section of the tube. What is the proper way to calculate the overall probability of the particle making it through all 5 sections without sticking?

Assume the probability of sticking is about 0.02 for each section, although it varies slightly. My initial assumption was to add all the probabilities together as they seem to me to be mutually exclusive events. Is this correct?

Comment: Making it through all the sections means "not getting stuck in the first section AND not getting stuch in the second section AND ... AND not getting stuck in the fifth section". So it's an intersection. Assuming independence, this is the product of the probabilities of not getting stuck in each section, like the two answers just posted below suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(S_{i})$ = the probability of making it through a section.

The probability of making it through all the sections, assuming that each event is an independent one, is given by

$\prod_{i=1}^{5}P(S_{i})$ = $0.98^{5} = 0.9039$ (4s.f.)

Edit:

Also note, that mutually exclusive events, are events which cannot occur simultaneously. For example, obtaining a $2$ versus obtaining a $3$ on a dice roll are mutually exclusive events. In this case, your events are independent ones. This means that the outcome of one event does not affect the outcome of another event, or more precisely:

$P(A|B) = P(A)$

where $P(A|B)$ denotes the probability of $A$ given $B$

Answer (score 1):

Let us say, $p$ will be the probability that it will we stuck in the tube.

Probability that it'll not be stuck : $1-p$

What we want is that it passes through all of them without getting stuck.

i.e. $$\underbrace {(1-p)\times(1-p)\dots (1-p)}_{5 ~~ \text {times}}=(1-p)^5$$

Multiplication means **And** ; Addition means **Or**

You want particle to pass through section $1$ **and** section $2$ **and** section $3$ $\dots$

Therefore, here we have multiplied all the $5$ probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You're assumption, though close is a little bit off. You'll get a number very close when working with small probabilities, but here's the problem. Imagine 3 segments each with a 50% probability to catch the dust. There's nothing wrong with this sceneario, but just adding gives you 150%.

What you do instead is convert them to the probability of going through, then treat them like independent events. So in this case it has a 98% chance to go through so you do 0.98x0.98x0.98x0.98x0.98=0.90. It's generally easier to picture probabilities as a series of dice rolls, in this case it's one roll per tube, but what's often more helpful is to imagine rolling for each tube right at the start before it even enters to see if it would get stuck if it did reach that tube. Now it's obvious that it'll only get through if you roll in the top 98% on *every* tube and will get stuck at some point otherwise. This is why you can't treat them as mutually exclusive, even though it can only get stuck on 1 tube you can say that it would have been stuck according to the rolls you made at the beginning.